# How to insert AngularJS array into mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, angularjs

I can't find solution to my problem...

I've created some kind of deck builder and when I choose cards to deck (which is empty on the begining `$scope.deck = []`) I would like to insert it to database.

I have form like this:

```
<form name="myform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="showCrudData.name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="type">Deck Type</label>
                    <input type="text" id="type" name="type" ng-model="showCrudData.type" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="class">Class</label>
                    <input type="text" id="class" name="class" ng-model="showCrudData.class" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="author">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author" name="author" ng-model="showCrudData.author" class="form-control" />
                </div>


                    <label for="cards">Deck</label>
                    <p type="value" id="cards" name="cards" ng-model="showCrudData.cards">{{cards}}</p>     

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" ng-hide="showCrudData.id" ng-click="addData()">Add</a>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
            </form>
```

Im trying to insert `{{cards}}` into database as u can see, but its not working.

Here is my testing page where Im trying to solve the problem. The Deck label before choosing cards is looking like this `[]`

[image]

And thats part of my PHP file where I insert values into table

```
 case "add":
            if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO decks values ('',:nm,:tp,:cl,:au,:cd)";
                $insert = $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array(":nm"=>$_POST['data']['name'],":tp"=>$_POST['data']['type'],":cl"=>$_POST['data']['class'],":au"=>$_POST['data']['author'],":cd"=>print_r($_POST['data']['cards'])));
```

I tried to solve problem adding `print_r`, but it didnt work because its just adding number "1" into column "deck" in table.

Comment: If you `var_dump($_POST['data']);`, what's showing in `cards`? And what data type is the cards/cl column?

Comment: I think it's better to receive it with `$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( "php://input" ) );` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Guys I guess I need to change something here: `":cd"=>print_r($_POST['data']['cards']` because rest values inserts into database

Comment: Right. You need to verify what is in `$_POST['data']['cards']`, and the datatype of the column you're trying to insert it into.

Comment: datatype of the column is just "text" and in `$_POST['data']['cards']` is this I think `<p type="value" id="cards" name="cards" ng-model="showCrudData.cards">{{cards}}</p> `

Comment: That's the part of your form, not the data. You need to var_dump or log `$_POST['data']['cards']` to see **exactly** what it contains.

Comment: I dont know how to check it... I did `log($_POST['data']['cards'])` and after pushing some cards into `$scope.decks=[]` in db column there is value `-INF`